# Toolbar HOME not working when CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Posting this now, will update with more specific XML when I get home, but I have a layout setup:

Coordinator
- Appbar
-- Collapsing
--- ImageView
--- Toolbar
-- Frame/Recycler (fragment loaded)

And everything is cool, the Home/Back button works in the toolbar when the CollapsingToolbarLayout is expanded.  But as soon as the title of the collapsing toolbar moves into the spot beside the Home button, the button is no longer clickable.

The back button is responding to touches all the way up until its nearly almost collapsed.

It's as if the Title in the collapsing toolbar is catching the touch events and consuming them.  But I couldn't find anything from looking around that might explain that.

I'll post more complete Xml after work.  But hopefully someone has had something similar just from the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved ish. I was using a base activity and common XML file and for some reason it was not liking that. I created a new XML by copying the common and adding the nested scroll view to the activity instead of fragment.  Now the fragment is just a linear layout.